# Ruby - Socks4 proxy with WWW::Mechanize and NET::HTTP::GET

Tags: ruby, proxy, rubygems, mechanize-ruby

I searched on google and read in the ruby manuals, but I couldn't find a way to use WWW::Mechanize and NET::HTTP::GET over a socks4 proxy.

I read, that WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of the UserAgent module, and that therefore the ->proxy() method would work. But the manual only talks about http, ftp and gopher proxy.

Any ideas how to support socks4? Here are the code snippets:

```
def get_request(url_in)
    url = URI.parse(url_in)
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path, {"User-Agent" => $UserAgent})

    res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http|
        http.request(req)
    }


    return res.body
end
```

```
 agent       = WWW::Mechanize.new
    agent.user_agent_alias('Windows Mozilla')
    page        = agent.get("urlhere")
    post_form   = page.form('post')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to look at [Ruby socksify](http://socksify.rubyforge.org/). I don't think that the HTTP client has any support for SOCKS proxies; only HTTP proxies for HTTP.

Comment: Homepage is dead, archive here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170127085053/http://socksify.rubyforge.org/